# Colour of lines on Graph in Excel automatically matches the colour of the cell it relates

Tags: excel, charts

I have two different sets of data.
One is a chart stating the unique code of a sample and the group it belongs to. I have used conditional formatting so that all lines of data which are the same group are filled with the same colour.
Each unique sample code has a set of data it belongs to which I want to plot as a line graph. However, I want each line to automatically match the color that is associated with the unique code based on the group its in.

I have spent what seems like hours on this to no avail. I cant seem to find anyway to automatically set the color of the line.

Any solutions on how I could approach this (or if its just not possible) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're most likely going to need code (e.g. VBA).